# How can I make my layout have TableRows of equal height?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

My layout is like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_page1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TableRow
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="60dip"
                 android:gravity="right"
                  >

             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/string1"
                android:id="@+id/textview1"/>
             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:width="200dp"
                 android:inputType="number"/>
             </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:gravity="right"

                >
              <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/string2"
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"/>

             <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:width="200dp"
                    />
                .........
```

The distance between TableRows seems not so regular: some of them are too close and some of them are too far. I don't want to use android:paddingTop adjust them one by one.

is there any easy way to make same distance between them? Currently it looks like this:

[image: Picture of layout as it is now with varying row heights]

Comment: This is my layout picture->[http://imm.io/1bWnk](http://imm.io/1bWnk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@giga_abhi is spot on, but I would add that in each TableRow, you also need:

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

and in the `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and in the `ScrollView`:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: any idea about this issue? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087668/how-do-i-wrap-a-second-text-around-first-text-title-both-are-in-text-view

Comment: @JusticeBauer I've had a go, but it's not exactly elegant!

Answer (score 1):

In the `LinearLayout` set:

```
android:weightSum="(no of tables say 3)"`
```

and in each `TableRow` add this line:

```
android:layout_weight="1"`
```

This will form TableRow with same height as your orientation is Vertical. The only part remains is adjusting height of elements inside TableRow.